# What does this "classifiers": [] mean?

Tags: watson, visual-recognition

Hi I am currently trying to utilize Watson's Visual Reco Service and I am getting a really weird response. After reading the documentaion I am guessing this photo doesn't meet the threshold value but I am not actually sure. Here's the a snippet of one of my response:

```
{ "classifiers": [{ 
    "classes": [ { "class": "classname", "score": 0.522029 } ], 
    "classifier_id": "normalLeft_329785087", "name": "normalLeft" } ], 
    "image": "Testing_Left.zip/80589N.jpg" 
}, 
{ 
    "classifiers": [], 
    "image": "Testing_Left.zip/81860Y.jpg" 
},
```

Another issue related to this is that sometimes my zip files aren't recognized by watson. Is there any particular reason why watson would have difficulties with zip files?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> After reading the documentaion I am guessing this photo doesn't meet the threshold value but I am not actually sure.

That's exactly it.  It means none of the classes in the classifiers applied to the image `Testing_Left.zip/81860Y.jpg` returned a score above the `threshold`.  By default for custom classifiers, the threshold is 0.5  You can set the threshold parameter to 0 if you would like to see all each score per class per image.

> Is there any particular reason why watson would have difficulties with zip files?

We have observed problems with some zip files with files or directories inside which have extended character sets, such as accented letters.  Could that be the case for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response matt! Now the responses i get make a lot of sense. About my zip files i've rezipped them using the zip command it's now working great. Thanks for your help!